# how wors coalesce function with sum

Tags: sql, sum, coalesce

I got 2 table like it

```
table 1

id   cost

1     200
2     300
3     500
4     700
NULL  NULL
NULL  NULL
```

```
table 2 
1     200
2     300
3     500
4     700
5     1000
6     2500
```

and I did it :

```
sum(coalesce(table1.cost,table2.cost))
```

my aim is to got

```
200+300+500+700+1000+2500=  5200
```

If I do

```
sum(coalesce(table1.cost,table2.cost))
```

I got

```
200+300+500+700+1000+2500=  5200
```

OR I GOT IT ?

```
200+300+500+700+200+300+500+700+1000+2500=  6900
```

Thanks for answer, I'm curious to know how to have only 5200 and not 6900

I use snowflake SQL

Comment: Show *complete* queries, not just some expressions out of context. Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please share you queries to have more understanding of the problem.

With the mere data provided, I think you are looking for Full Outer Join as you need to include data from both tables. I have built a solution in SQL server using table variables. Both the queries gives the same result as 5200.

```
DECLARE @table1 table(Id INT NULL, Cost INT NULL) 
DECLARE @table2 table(Id INT NULL, Cost INT NULL) 

INSERT INTO @table1(Id, Cost)
VALUES(1, 200), (2, 300), (3, 500), (4, 700), (NULL, NULL), (NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO @table2(Id, Cost)
VALUES(1, 200), (2, 300), (3, 500), (4, 700), (5, 1000), (6, 2500)

SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(t1.Cost, t2.Cost))
FROM 
    @table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    @table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id

SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(t2.Cost, t1.Cost))
FROM 
    @table1 t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    @table2 t2
    ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```